# A Future or coroutine is required - asyncio

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, async-await, python-asyncio

I'm trying to asynchronously load content of a web page. I have used **requests_html**, as I face some problem installing it on my server so I am using **asyncio**

```
@asyncio.coroutine
async def extract_feature():
    try:
        count = 0
        key = ''
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        response = await loop.run_in_executor(None, requests.get, link)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response, "html.parser")
        return soup
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
result = loop.run_until_complete(extract_feature)
```

But this raises **A Future or coroutine is required**.

One thing to mentioned I'm using *Python 3.5.0 (v3.5.0:374f501f4567)* which doesn't support run.

Comment: The code as shown is not valid syntax. The ``try:`` must have a matching ``except`` or ``finally`` clause. Please post the traceback you get and the actual code you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `extract_feature` before passing it to `run_until_complete`, i.e.:

```
result = loop.run_until_complete(extract_feature())
```

Also, the `asyncio.coroutine` decorator shouldn't be used with functions already defined as `async def` - just omit it.